# How to give root level access?

Tags: mount

When I tried to mount my hard drive following error got displayed.
I am very new to linux. Please help.

```
mount /dev/sda2 /media/shashi/ -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222
mount: only root can do that
```

what should I do to give root level access?

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo`:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/shashi/ -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222
```

Comment: I did as you told @eric but following error caught me again.

Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Comment: @Shashi See http://askubuntu.com/q/145902/65926

Comment: When I do this, the mounted folders are read only and I require root access just to change the contents of the mounted folders!  Is there a method that doesn't involve crippling the feature?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to mount the partition as root unless you add an entry to `/etc/fstab`

If you want to mount the partition as a user, without root access,

Open `/etc/fstab` as root. In a terminal, run

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

At the bottom of the file add

```
/dev/sda2 /media/shashi/ ntfs users,noauto,nls=utf8,umask=0222 0 0
```

Change "noauto" to auto if you want it to automatically mount when you boot.

Then, make the mount point if it does not exist

```
sudo mkdir /media/shashi
```

Then you can mount as a user.

```
mount /media/shashi
```

For details see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

Comment: Its not working.